# Migrating standalone.xml from Wildfly 8.1 to JBOSS EAP 6

Tags: configuration, jboss, migration, wildfly

We have an javaee application already running on Wildfly 8.1 and we want to migrate it on JBoss EAP 6 because our customer needs a commercial license.

On Wildfly we have the following configuration

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.2">
...
<concurrent>
    <context-services>
        <context-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" use-transaction-setup-provider="true"/>
    </context-services>
    <managed-thread-factories>
        <managed-thread-factory name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default" context-service="default"/>
    </managed-thread-factories>
    <managed-executor-services>
        <managed-executor-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000" core-threads="50" max-threads="500" keepalive-time="5000" queue-length="1000"/>
    </managed-executor-services>
    <managed-scheduled-executor-services>
        <managed-scheduled-executor-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000" core-threads="2" keepalive-time="3000"/>
    </managed-scheduled-executor-services>
</concurrent>
<default-bindings context-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" jms-connection-factory="java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" managed-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" managed-scheduled-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" managed-thread-factory="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default"/>
```

How could we configure it on JBoss EAP? We read the documentation but the "concurrent" tag does not exist and we want to manage the concurrent threads.

Answer (score 2):

Wildfly 8 was the first version towards a Java EE 7 compliant application server. Wildfly 10 is the latest version in that line.

JBoss EAP 7 is the supported version corresponding to WildFly 10. It is now in Beta.

So in short if you want to use the concurrent tag then you need to use JBoss EAP 7.

Comment: Thank for your answer but JBOSS EAP 7 is a Beta and our customer needs a commercial license. So we must downgrade to JBOSS EAP 6.

Answer (score 1):

You're actually downgrading. JBoss EAP 6.2 is based on JBoss Application Server (AS) 7.3.0.Final. See the [JBoss EAP component matrix](https://access.redhat.com/articles/112673) for reference.

As you can see, EAP 7 is not there, as it was not released yet. The page is being updated as the component versions settle. Once it's out there, instead of JBoss AS, there will be WildFly. For EAP 7, it will be WildFly 10.x, as ozOli wrote.

JBoss EAP 7 (not sure about WildFly 10) has a feature which takes your old `standalone.xml` and converts it to the new configuration - namespaces, subsystems.

Once there was a tool under development called [WindRide](https://github.com/OndraZizka/jboss-migration) which aimed at automated configuration migration, but that was cutted off few years back.

---

In addition to **automated server configuration migration**, there are tools to assist with **automated application migration**:

## [JBoss Windup](http://windup.jboss.org/) - pluggable customizable rule-based automated migration tool.

Pretty good*.

*) reference: me - I'm one of developers :)